# Image not displaying when generating a html page as pdf using mpdf library

Tags: php, html, pdf-generation, codeigniter-3

I am generating a html page as pdf in codeigniter.. the image in html page is not displaying in pdf document

```
public function nmms_halltickets($categ = 1) {
     // by kowshiga
      try {     
          $school_id = $this->session->userdata('udise');
              $name = date("Y") . 'NMMS Halltickets.pdf';

          $this->db->where('exam', $categ)
                    ->where('school_code',$school_id);
          $result = $this->db->get('halltickets')->result(); 

           foreach ($result as $ht) {
              $data['halltickets'] = $this->Admin_Model->gethalltickets($ht->candidate_name);

                 $html[]['content']= $this->load->view('hall_ticket', $data, true);
                // print_r($html);
                // exit();
          }

          $this->common->generate_pdf($html, $name, $output_type = 'D', null, 10, null, 0, $orientation = 'P');
      } catch (Exception $e) {
          log_message('error', $e->getMessage());
      }
  }
```

Comment: Add some delay before generate PDF, image takes some times to load

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your image path is correct first

Comment: yeah the path is correct... the image is coming in html page.. but in pdf it is not coming